# Reset git repository to specific commit from specific branch

Tags: git, reset

I was working on a branch which was in the following state

```
        A'--B'--C'--D'
       /
A--B--C--D
```

some very bad things happened and I have to go back to B' both locally and remote
so that the remote repository is the following

```
         A'--B'
        /
 A--B--C--D
```

For the local repository I did

```
git reset --hard <sha>
```

but how can I do that for the remote repository?

I should be able to do something like

git push origin mybranch --reset

but it's not in the man page

I tried creating a commit which would cancel the previous ones but

git add .

reports that there are no changes (expected since I'm exactly after the previous push)

So how can I reset the remote repository?

Comment: a bonus question would be: is there any way to remove the D' and C' commit from git history git log and generally all existence as if they never happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Removing Commit from History

All you really need to do is be on the B' branch, and then go `git push --force` to overwrite the current commit pointer for that branch. If you don't have your remotes set up as tracking branches, you may need to do `git push --force origin <branchname>` instead.

C' and D' will remain in the reflog and as objects in the repository until they are eventually pruned, but shouldn't show up as part of any log history unless you start digging into the plumbing.

#### Removing Dangling Objects from the Repository

If you want C' and D' out of the repository altogether, you can call `git prune --expire now` in both repositories. That should remove the dangling objects altogether.

Comment: Note that you do not want to call `git prune` unless you have a good reason — it destroys garbage objects, which are very useful if you want to recover lost data with Git.

Comment: @AlexanderGladysh This is exactly the use case for git-prune(1): to remove dangling objects entirely, which is what the OP asked for. Also, note that one may have to run git-repack(1) and git-prune-packed(1) if the dangling commits have already been packed.

Comment: @CodeGnome Nevertheless, I feel that a warning is needed in this case — git prune will remove *all* dangling objects (which usually is OK, but you have to know what you're doing).

Answer (score 4):

To override a tracked remote branch with yours, do `git push origin --force mybranch`. (Or use `-f` instead of `--force`, or prefix the branch name with `+`: `git push origin +mybranch`.)

Note that you should warn any collaborators that may have changed your branch that it has been changed remotely, so they will not override it back. Because `git push` on their copies will do fast-forward for remote branch — unless you made at least one new commit to it, and `git pull` will not update their local version of a branch. Collaborators should do:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout mybranch
git rebase origin/mybranch
```

Updated for completeness: As @CodeGnome suggests, to completely remove commits from existence, run `git prune --expire now` on all Git repos that contained them. Be warned though, that this command will remove *all* dangling objects from Git, and will prevent recovery of any data that you 'lost' before you run it. It is usually OK, but you need to be warned anyway.

Update: as [this](https://wincent.com/wiki/Obliterating_a_Git_commit) page suggests, `git prune --expire now` will not clean commit from reflogs. See the link for the solution. For a less-invasive solution, try `git reflog expire --all mybranch`. You have to do this before you run `git prune`.

Sometimes it is more preferable to explicitly generate an "undo" commit that removes the changes (so old version and the fact of its removal are visible in history). There is a `git revert` command for it.